# How do I check if a sub string exist in a list nested in a dictionary?

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to check if a string, is a substring of any value in a list.
Example:

```
x = ['Hello, I\'m bob', 'Hello, I\'m Gabe']

if 'Gabe' in x:
    print('Gabe is in x[1]')
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I have tried to use: if 'Gabe' in x[:] thinking that might work. By the way, I'm a begginer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that `x` is defined as

```
x = ['Hello, I\'m bob', 'Hello, I\'m Gabe']
```

If you just want to know if the string 'Gabe' is in any of the strings in the list, then do

```
>>> any('Gabe' in s for s in x)
True
```

If you want to know which elements in the list do,

```
>>> [s for s in x if 'Gabe' in s]
["Hello, I'm Gabe"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to test against each string in the list separately.

```
x = ['Hello, I\'m bob', 'Hello, I\'m Gabe']

for i, s in enumerate(x):
  if 'Gabe' in s:
    print 'index:', i
```

Comment: How could I return what key that was. Like in this case it would be x[1]?

Comment: Yes, but this is a permanent output of x[1]. Say 'Gabe' was in x[0], how could I get it to detect that on its own?

Comment: It's not permanent.  Try switching the two strings in x.  index changes to 0.